# A Riddle of Many Faces

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

I have been many things in my life. Specifically, and in order, a monkey, a knife, a junkie, an alien, a lunatic, a cat, an aristocrat, a clown, and finally, an earthling.

What or who am I, and what do each of these things refer to?

Hints:

1. > The first was eponymous, the second a change, the third an explorer, the fourth an idol. The fifth just a lad, the sixth quite cool, the seventh pale and waifish, the eighth fond of ashes, the last a technophile.
2. > My left is big, my right changes size.
3. > Little Liza, Gnome, Andy Warhol, Starman, Drive-in, Big Brother, It's not the side effects, Little green, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> David Bowie

And the justification is:

> The varying stage characters created by Bowie over the years.

1. a monkey, & eponymous & Little Liza

   > His first stage name was **Davy Jones**, which also was the stage name of David Thomas "Davy" Jones of the Monkees; his first song was "Liza Jane"
2. a knife, & a change & Gnome

   > Then he changed his stage name to **David Bowie**, like the Bowie knife called after American frontiersman Jim Bowie; song "The Laughing Gnome"
3. a junkie, & an explorer & Andy Warhol

   > astronaut and space explorer **Major Tom**; the line "We know Major Tom's a junkie" occurs in the later song "Ashes to ashes"; Song "Andy Warhol" on "Hunky Dory";
4. an alien, & an idol & Starman

   > **Ziggy Stardust**= rock star and idol; album "Ziggy Stardust"; song "Starman";
5. a lunatic, & a lad & Drive-in

   > **Aladdin Sane** = "A Lad Insane";  the album includes the song "Drive-In Saturday"
6. a cat, & quite cool & Big Brother

   > **Halloween Jack** is "a real cool cat"; album "Diamond Dogs" with song "Big Brother";
7. an aristocrat, & pale and waifish & It's not the side effects

   > The "**Thin White Duke**" on "Station to station"; "It's not the side effects of the cocaine / I'm thinking that it must be love";
8. a clown, & fond of ashes & Little green

   > The music video of "Ashes to Ashes" featured Bowie dressed up as a **Pierrot clown**; "Ashes to Ashes" contains the line "But the little green wheels are following me"
9. and finally, an earthling & a technophile & I'm afraid

   > "I'm Afraid of Americans" on Bowie's techno album "**Earthling**"

Finally, hint 2 with "My left is big, my right changes size" refers to

> the permanently dilated pupil in Bowie's left eye.

Comment: BING!  Nailed it.  Congrats.